# Create linked clones of objects in PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint

Many graphics programs support dynamic clones of objects, i. e., whenever you change anything on the original object, it'll change all clones right away in the same manner. The reason I need this is that I have many copies of one and the same graphic across several slides. Ideally changing one should also alter the others.
Google didn't get me any further. Is someone aware of such a functionality?

Answer (score 1):

When you insert the graphic (via Insert | Picture), choose the picture then click the triangle next to Open and choose either Link to File or Insert and Link.

From then on, if you change the original picture file, PPT will update the graphic within the presentation when you open the PPTX.

Insert and Link is probably the best option; if the linked picture file isn't available, PPT will use the inserted copy of the graphic.